# Upload a file using PHP and Jquery without displaying the browse window?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to upload a file using PHP and Jquery.I know the path where it is saved`(Path is static with the same file name)`.
Every time when the user click the upload button then I need to upload the file in the backend and displaying only the uploading gif image in the front end.So is it possible to make the upload without displaying the browse window using Jquery and PHP?

Comment: without displaying browse window? then how you planning to select a file?

Comment: I know the path.So I want to give the path with the file name.So  is it possible to upload a file?

Comment: I hope it's impossible because you could load silently any file from my pc.

Comment: +1 for Great Thinking...Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

for that u can use jQuery Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/demo/

Comment: But it opens the browse window for upload.I dont really need that browse window.Do you have any other ideas?